# Save Doobie stream from database to file

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect, doobie

Doobie select returns an `fs2.Stream(doobie.ConnectionIO, String)`. If we need to write it to file the obvious option is to call `stream.compile.toList.transact(transactor)` and then save this list to file.

**Is there a way to save result in a streaming way without converting it to list?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to convert the `cats.IO` operations into the `doobie.ConnectionIO` with `Async[doobie.ConnectionIO].liftIO(IO(...))`. This allows to combine file operations with database operations nicely. Here is a complete example program that streams results to file.

```
package com.example

import java.io.BufferedWriter

import better.files.File
import cats.effect._
import cats.implicits._
import doobie._
import doobie.implicits._
import fs2.Stream


object Example extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val xa = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](
      "org.postgresql.Driver",     // driver classname
      "jdbc:postgresql:example_db",     // connect URL (driver-specific)
      "postgres",                  // user
      ""                          // password
    )

    val drop = sql"drop table if exists example".update.run
    val create =
      sql"create table if not exists example (id serial primary key, string_value text not null)".update.run
    val insert = Update[String]("insert into example (string_value) values (?)")
      .updateMany(List("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"))

    val setup = for {
      _ <- drop.transact(xa)
      _ <- create.transact(xa)
      _ <- insert.transact(xa)
    } yield ()

    val select: Stream[doobie.ConnectionIO, String] =
      sql"select string_value from example".query[String].stream
    val output = writeToFile(select).compile.drain.transact(xa)

    for {
      _ <- setup
      _ <- output
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }

  private def writeToFile(result: Stream[doobie.ConnectionIO, String]): Stream[doobie.ConnectionIO, Unit] = {
    Stream.resource(writer("./example.txt")).flatMap { writer =>
      result.intersperse("\n").chunks.evalMap { chunk =>
        Async[doobie.ConnectionIO].liftIO(IO(
          chunk.foreach(writer.write)
        ))
      }
    }
  }

  private def writer(path: String): Resource[doobie.ConnectionIO, BufferedWriter] = {
    Resource.make {
      Async[doobie.ConnectionIO].liftIO(IO(
        File(path).newBufferedWriter
      ))
    } { outStream =>
      Async[doobie.ConnectionIO].liftIO(IO(
        outStream.close())
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use the native [`witeAll`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-io_2.12/2.2.1/fs2-io_2.12-2.2.1-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/io/file/index.html#writeAll[F[_]](path:java.nio.file.Path,blocker:cats.effect.Blocker,flags:Seq[java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption])(implicitevidence$8:cats.effect.Sync[F],implicitevidence$9:cats.effect.ContextShift[F]):fs2.Pipe[F,Byte,Unit]) provided by **fs2**.

Comment: I tried that, it did not work because `writeAll` needs `Concurrent[doobie.ConnectionIO]` which I do not have. If you know of a way to make it work, please post an answer, I would really like to see that.

Comment: No I mean,you have to transact the `doobie.ConnectionI` to a `cats.effect.IO` or something else, that is correct. But, my advice was then in the writing part, not doing it they way you show.

Comment: That is the whole point, if you make an `IO` from a `ConnectionIO` then you will have a list, not a stream. Please, post an answer if you see how to do that, you can take my code as a base and change just the writing part.

Comment: `stream.transact(xa).through(fs2.io.writeAll(???))` - https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/04-Selecting.html#final-streaming

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import doobie.implicits._
import doobie.util.transactor.Transactor
import fs2.text
import fs2.io.file.{Files, Path}

object Example {
  def queryToFile: IO[Unit] =
    sql"select string_value from example"
      .query[String]
      .stream
      .transact(xa)
      .through(text.utf8.encode[IO])
      .through(Files[IO].writeAll(Path("path-to-file")))
      .compile
      .drain
}
```